# Creating an iterator in Java

Tags: java, iterator

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class MapObjects<MapleMapObject> {
    private Map map;
    private HashMap<Integer, MapleMapObject> objects;

    public MapObjects(Map map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.objects = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void add(MapleMapObject object) {
        objects.put(map.getObjectId(), object);

        onAdd();
    }

    public void remove(MapleMapObject object) {
        onRemove();

        objects.remove(object.getObjectId());
    }

    protected abstract void onAdd();

    protected abstract void onRemove();
}
```

I want to create an iterator so I can iterate over classes that extend from this class. For example, if I have a class named `MapCharacters extends MapObjects<Character>`, I want to be able to do the following:

```
characters = new MapCharacters(this);
for (Character character : characters)
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: For the enhanced `for` loop syntax to work, `MapCharacters` must implement `Iterable<Character>`.

Comment: Why do you use MapObjects<MapleMapObject> in your code sample and then talk about MapObjects<Character> in your question? You should make it generic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to be able to iterate over `objects` map, you can just call `values()` on that and then create an iterator from that value set:

```
public abstract class MapObjects<MapleMapObject> implements Iterable<MapleMapObject> {

    ...

    @Override public Iterator<MapleMapObject> iterator() {
        return objects.values().iterator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return `objects.values().iterator()` but you should be aware that this iterator has a `remove()` method that you can use to remove entries from `objects` without `onRemove()` being called. This may or may not be what you want.

If this is not what you want, you can return an `Iterator` where the `remove` method throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(objects.values()).iterator();
```

Alternatively, if you want an `Iterator` with a `remove` method that removes an entry and invokes your `onRemove()` method, you would have to write a class implementing `Iterator` yourself. I think something like this would work.

```
public abstract class MapObjects<MapleMapObject> implements Iterable<MapleMapObject> {

    ...

    @Override 
    public Iterator<MapleMapObject> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<MapleMapObject>() {

            private final Iterator<MapleMapObject> iterator = objects.values().iterator();

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return iterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public MapleMapObject next() {
                return iterator.next();
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                onRemove();
                iterator.remove();
            }
        };
    }
}
```